# Place a Button in a EditView using TableLayout

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, tablelayout

I am trying to make a search text field with a search button that is clickable (no rightDrawable stuff) in TableLayout. I have seen this done in RelativeLayout but I do not know how to do this in TableLayout. Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="android.tabcards.app.MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/searchTableRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter search key" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
    ______________________
   |Enter Text Here    |->|
    ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Edit: here is what it looks like now:
[image: img]

Comment: whats the problem with ur xml?

Comment: I want the Button to be inside the EditText, like shown at the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to center your `EditText` within your relative layout to align with the button.

**sample:**

```
      <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:hint="Enter search key" />
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Also, is it possible to make the button smaller (height)? Because at the moment it looks like this: http://imgur.com/VrJYpN0

Comment: Just to let you know the button spans over the height of the text field

Comment: @gedr just add padding it in, button padding.

Comment: but it still goes over the text field (the button goes bellow the line below the text field). See the image above ^

Comment: @gedr I would recommend re-sizing your image, without padding

Comment: Can I have 1 image for all densities? or do I have to have more than 1?

Comment: @gedr yes you need images for different density, or you can just resize it programatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59776/discussion-between-gedr-and-rod-algonquin).

Comment: can you enter the chat room? I need to ask you some more stuff. Please

Comment: @gedr I cant I am on my phone. cant enter the chat room.